# How to get correct method scope using Google signin with angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, google-signin

I am 95% of the way to getting google signin to work. Trying to figure out 2 problems with the code. Here is my current code (simplified)

```
loginWithGoogle(): void {
  //this one works
  google.accounts.id.initialize({
    client_id: 'appid.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    callback: this.handleCredentialResponse
  });
  google.accounts.id.prompt();
}

handleCredentialResponse(response: any) {
  //makes it here
  this.processLogin(response);
}

processLogin(response: any) {
  //doesn't make it here
}
```

Problem #1: When `google.accounts.id.initialize` fails, I can see the error on the console log, but how do I get that error in my code? I feel like I need some kind of error callback, but none is shown in the documentation. Is there now way to get that error message?

Problem #2: callback works great getting me to handleCredentialResponse, but then the "this" is no longer in the correct scope, so it cannot make it to the next method. How can I structure this to maintain the correct angular scope?

getting : `TypeError: this.authorizedLogin is not a function.` error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by using ngZone:

```
  google.accounts.id.initialize({
    client_id: "appId.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    callback: (window as any)['handleCredentialResponse'] =
      (response: any) => this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.handleCredentialResponse(response);
      })
  });
  google.accounts.id.prompt();
```

As for the error message, it appears there is no solution and likely google simply forgot to provide an error callback method.